# how to do oneToMany mapping in hibernate if one table already has data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to do mapping in hibernate i.e one to many, I have one **"m_role"** table and another is **"m_privilege"** table, so I wanna assign many privilege to role table, but I already have values inside my privilege table so I wanna map many privilege to one role, so how I can do using hibernate.

Below are my Model class:

```
@Table(name = "m_role")
@Entity
public class MasterRole {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name="trans_role_privilege")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<MasterPrivilege> mMasterPrivilege = new HashSet<MasterPrivilege>();

public Set<MasterPrivilege> getmMasterPrivilege() {
    return mMasterPrivilege;
}

public void setmMasterPrivilege(Set<MasterPrivilege> mMasterPrivilege) {
    this.mMasterPrivilege = mMasterPrivilege;
}

@Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
private String role;

@Column(name = "description", nullable = true)
private String description;

@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
private Integer status;

@Column(name = "creationDate", nullable = true)
private Date creationDate;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}
```

and another table for privilege:

```
@Table(name = "m_privilege")
@Entity
@Embeddable
public class MasterPrivilege {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
@Column(name = "Pid", nullable = false)
private Integer Pid;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "description", nullable = true)
private String description;

@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
private Integer status;

@Column(name = "creationDate", nullable = true)
private Date creationDate;

public Integer getPid() {
    return Pid;
}

public void setPid(Integer pid) {
    Pid = pid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}
```

So after running this will create an trans_role_privilege table to keep role_id and privilege_id. So in this I have already values in the privilege table. Now I want to map if we add new role with privilege id to trans_role_privilege.

Comment: Since each role can have many privileges (as you mentioned), I would first have a bag in my role table with a one-to-many relation to the trans_role_privilege table, and the trans_role_privilege hbm would have the role id and the privilege id mapped to the respective tables. I think you are not using hbm and using the models itself to do the mapping.

Comment: @Jilna hi thanks for your response , but what do you mean by hdm ??